# Hardware suggestions for a simple data acquisition unit

Tags: usb

I am attempting a simple data acquisition project. I have a 5V analog signal from a pressure transducer on 2-3 channels. I need to convert this to a digital signal that I can acquire on my PC. Ideally, this would involve a USB. I need to monitor this signal real-time and be able to export to CSV or text format. Sampling frequency is not critical (20 kHz is ok).

Hoping to purchase a data acquisition card/box that would work with minimal programming and tinkering. Would be nice if it worked with a 1/4" jack on the analog side (or even RCA or 3.5 mm). Also looking for guidance on software for this project. I feel like this should be an easy project but having difficulty finding exactly what I need and since I haven't done anything like this before, a bit afraid to jump in. Hoping someone can point me in the direction regarding what to buy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that may meet your requirements, for a rather good price (US Dollars) in a product called the [DATAQ DI-1100 data acquisition starter kit](https://www.dataq.com/products/di-1100/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIoqSTsqfj2QIVl0wNCh2snwz3EAYYASABEgKSi_D_BwE).

[image: DI-1100 kit]

Four analog inputs up to +/-10v with provided software allowing for computer data storage and processing. The connections are screw terminals, not mini-plugs, although it's a simple matter to add such a junction device of your own design and construction.

The specifications note that you should be able to accomplish 20-24kHz sampling for the limited number of inputs you require.

There are PDF documents on the site providing greater detail as well as the operation manual. The manual indicates a mini-USB is used for power and communication.

The included software manual has a section allowing for exporting files to be used in Excel, although it references the more-or-less universal CSV file format, precluding the data from being restricted to Excel.